# Java functional generics

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

ComputeIfAbsent method of Map has following declaration:

`computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction)`.

Why wasn't parameter declared as `Function<K,V>` when K and V types are not used anywhere else?

Now I understand that K and V are very important and they are part of the Map class declaration.

Comment: Generally to make clear what is acceptable. For Example you can pass anything into the function as long is the super class is K and for the second parameter as long as it extends V. Else it could lead to missconceptions.

Comment: `K` and `V` is parameters of `Map` why do you think they is not used?

Comment: It's worth looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super) to start with. I'd probably go even so far as to say this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`K` and `V` are part of the type of the mapping function. So they are actually used. Specifically, they determine the acceptable and most general bounds for the argument type and the return type of the mapping function.

For

```
Function<? super K,? extends V> mappingFunction
```

this means that you can pass any function that is able to at least map everything that can serve as a key in your map (thus `? super K`) and maps those keys to values that can be put into the map (thus `extends V`). In effect this gives you more flexibility in the choice of the mapping function.

In more theoretical terms: under sub-typing functions are contravariant in its argument type and covariant in its return type. This determines the type of `mappingFunction` to `Function<? super K,? extends V>` when regarding `Map<K, V>` as a function from `K` to `V`.

Answer (score 4):

**Simple example:**

```
Map<String,Object> myMap = ...
Function<Object,String> myFunc = Object::toString;
myMap.computeIfAbsent("42", myFunc);
```

**Is this acceptable?**

Well, given the type of myFunc is `Function<Object,String>`, and we have a `Map<String,Object>`, which sounds like there is a problem. It certainly wouldn't compile if you only accepted `Function<K,V>`.

But when you look at it closer, there isn't anything wrong. Not only does the code demonstrably work, it's also easy to see why it works: `"42"` is an instance of `String`, which has a `toString()` method. That method returns a `String`, which is of course an `Object`. So of course it's fine.

And this "fine"-ness is what is expressed by `Function<? super K, ? extends V>`.

Comment: Actually, `myMap.computeIfAbsent("42", Object::toString)` still compiled, if the method’s parameter was declared `Function<K,V>`, because the compiler is smart enough to bind `Object::toString` as `Function<String,Object>`, e.g. you could also write `Function<String,Object> f = Object::toString;` without getting an error. That’s why lambda expressions and method references make bad examples. Try existing functions, e.g. `computeIfAbsent(myMap, "42", Function.identity())` would not compile anymore. But then, the questions is just a duplicate of “what is PECS”…

Comment: @Holger You're of course right. I'll fix the example.